# console system() c++ infinite loop while trying to do ipconfig

Tags: c++, console-application

I'm currently learning c++ from scratch, I've previously developed apps with C# using Visual Studio but I'm a total noob with C++, I'm trying to make a small console exe that releases and renews the ip while practicing using headers and differents .cpp files.

The issue is that when I run the local windows debugger from visual studio 2015 the code runs perfectly and does everything I'm trying to. But when I build and try to run the .exe file it goes into an infinite loop stating endlessly the output from the std::cout <<"Realizando ipconfig Release", I have localized the issue to when it tries to run the system("ipconfig /release"). Why does this happen? and How can I fix it?

This is the header

```
#pragma once
#ifndef HeaderIp
#define HeaderIp
int Release();
int Renew();
#endif // !HeaderIp
```

This is the release.cpp

```
   #include <stdlib.h>
int Release()
{
    if (system(nullptr)==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        system("ipconfig /release");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

This is the renew.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>;
int Renew()
{
    if (system(nullptr)==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        system("ipconfig /renew");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

and finally this is the ipconfig.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "HeaderIp.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    std::cout << "Realizando ipconfig Release" << std::endl;
    int i = 0;                                                      //Bit de informacion de status de CPU
    i = Release();
    if (i == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error al liberar IP" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Ip Liberado correctamente" << std::endl;
    }
    i = Renew();
    if (i == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error al renovar IP" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Ip renovado correctamente" << std::endl;
    }

system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Where is the executable located when you run it? It appears as if it's recursively calling itself. Consider not calling your program "ipconfig"

Comment: The program calls itself....

Comment: Oh my, I feel dumb now haha, the program was located in the x64 release folder of the project, didn't know it could call itself by doing that, I changed it to Autoip and now it runs thank you very much.

Comment: *`exit;`*? C++ isn't Python... Is your compiler giving you any warnings? They're *warnings* for a reason, you know...?

Comment: Nope, the compiler wasn't giving any warning.

Answer (score 0):

It's unusual, and indeed generally [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong) to use `system` in C++. If you were to [manage DHCP leases using `IpReleaseAddress` and `IpRenewAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366290(v=vs.85).aspx), instead, you might find your problem *disappears*.

You can use `std::cin.sync()` instead of `system("pause")`, too.

`exit;` probably doesn't do what you want it to, as you're only *referring* to the function, you're not *calling* it, so... it'll do *nothing*.

The semicolon in `#include <stdlib.h>;` is an error, and you should be including `<cstdlib>` and `<cstdio>` rather than `<stdlib.h>` and `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: Actually the answer to my issue was what @Tas stated, it was recursively calling itself as I stated above in a comment, I changed the name of the program and it does exactly what I was trying to, but thanks for the heads up on the IpReleaseAddress and IpRenewAddress I will check on them.

Comment: @Joesteva Precisely. If you removed the `system` call and instead used the API functions I mentioned (like a **normal** programmer would), your program would not recursively invoke itself, because there's no `system` call to cause that.